# Flatten Scala Try

Tags: scala, try-catch, scala-2.10

Is there a simple way to flatten a collection of try's to give either a success of the try values, or just the failure?
For example:

```
def map(l:List[Int]) = l map {
  case 4 => Failure(new Exception("failed"))
  case i => Success(i)
}

val l1 = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
val result1 = something(map(l1))

result1: Failure(Exception("failed"))

val l2 = List(1,2,3,5,6)
val result2 = something(map(l2)) 

result2: Try(List(1,2,3,5,6))
```

And can how would you handle multiple Failures in the collection?

Comment: Please say how your result should look like. `List(1, 2, 3, Exception, 5, 7)`?

Comment: Scalaz would call this operation `sequence`, but it's sadly missing from the standard library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe not as simple as you hoped for, but this works:

```
def flatten[T](xs: Seq[Try[T]]): Try[Seq[T]] = {
  val (ss: Seq[Success[T]]@unchecked, fs: Seq[Failure[T]]@unchecked) =
    xs.partition(_.isSuccess)

  if (fs.isEmpty) Success(ss map (_.get))
  else Failure[Seq[T]](fs(0).exception) // Only keep the first failure
}

val xs = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
val ys = List(1,2,3,5,6)

println(flatten(map(xs))) // Failure(java.lang.Exception: failed)
println(flatten(map(ys))) // Success(List(1, 2, 3, 5, 6))
```

Note that the use of `partition` is not as type safe as it gets, as witnessed by the `@unchecked` annotations. In that respect, a `foldLeft` that accumulates two sequences `Seq[Success[T]]` and `Seq[Failure[T]]` would be better.

If you wanted to keep all failures, you can use this:

```
def flatten2[T](xs: Seq[Try[T]]): Either[Seq[T], Seq[Throwable]] = {
  val (ss: Seq[Success[T]]@unchecked, fs: Seq[Failure[T]]@unchecked) =
    xs.partition(_.isSuccess)

  if (fs.isEmpty) Left(ss map (_.get))
  else Right(fs map (_.exception))
}

val zs = List(1,4,2,3,4,5,6)

println(flatten2(map(xs))) // Right(List(java.lang.Exception: failed))
println(flatten2(map(ys))) // Left(List(1, 2, 3, 5, 6))
println(flatten2(map(zs))) // Right(List(java.lang.Exception: failed, 
                           //            java.lang.Exception: failed))
```

Comment: +1 " In that respect, a foldLeft that accumulates two sequences Seq[Success[T]] and Seq[Failure[T]] would be better. "

Yes ! There is so many validation or failures types in the scala ecosystem (Option, Either, Try, scalaz.Disjunction, scalaz.Validation,...), and still I couldn't find any such double seq fold exemples among the public methods and common patterns.

Answer (score 29):

This is pretty close to minimal for fail-first operation:

```
def something[A](xs: Seq[Try[A]]) =
  Try(xs.map(_.get))
```

(to the point where you shouldn't bother creating a method; just use `Try`).  If you want all the failures, a method is reasonable; I'd use an `Either`:

```
def something[A](xs: Seq[Try[A]]) =
  Try(Right(xs.map(_.get))).
  getOrElse(Left(xs.collect{ case Failure(t) => t }))
```

Comment: Nice! (Although it re-throws the exception, if any) How would you extend it such that all exceptions are kept?

Comment: @mhs - If failure is uncommon or performance is not critical, you want the re-throw as it's the simplest way to deal with the problem.  The exception's stack trace has already been generated, so the throw/catch itself isn't too expensive.  If I wanted to keep all exceptions I'd pack them in an `Either` instead, e.g. as in my edit.

Answer (score 9):

A little less verbose, and more type safe:

```
def sequence[T](xs : Seq[Try[T]]) : Try[Seq[T]] = (Try(Seq[T]()) /: xs) {
    (a, b) => a flatMap (c => b map (d => c :+ d))
}
```

Results:

```
sequence(l1)
```

> res8: scala.util.Try[Seq[Int]] = Failure(java.lang.Exception: failed)

```
sequence(l2)
```

> res9: scala.util.Try[Seq[Int]] = Success(List(1, 2, 3, 5, 6))

Comment: It looks nice, though is there not going to be quite a performance hit with the append operation?

Comment: Fair point - I'd forgotten that the default `Seq` is a `List`. Add reverse/use a vector at your discretion!

Comment: Nice, I hadnt seen that foldLeft shortcut before `/:`

Answer (score 6):

As an addition to Impredicative's answer and comment, if you have both [scalaz-seven](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/tree/scalaz-seven) and [scalaz-contrib](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-contrib)/scala210 in your dependencies:

```
> scala210/console
[warn] Credentials file /home/folone/.ivy2/.credentials does not exist
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_17).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> import scala.util._
import scala.util._

scala> def map(l:List[Int]): List[Try[Int]] = l map {
     |   case 4 => Failure(new Exception("failed"))
     |   case i => Success(i)
     | }
map: (l: List[Int])List[scala.util.Try[Int]]

scala> import scalaz._, Scalaz._
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

scala> import scalaz.contrib.std.utilTry._
import scalaz.contrib.std.utilTry._

scala> val l1 = List(1,2,3,4,5,6)
l1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> map(l1).sequence
res2: scala.util.Try[List[Int]] = Failure(java.lang.Exception: failed)

scala> val l2 = List(1,2,3,5,6)
l2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 5, 6)

scala> map(l2).sequence
res3: scala.util.Try[List[Int]] = Success(List(1, 2, 3, 5, 6))
```

You need scalaz to get an `Applicative` [instance](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/std/List.scala#L14) for the `List` (hidden in the `MonadPlus` instance), to get the [`sequence`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Applicative.scala#L39) method. You need scalaz-contrib for the `Traverse` [instance](https://github.com/typelevel/scalaz-contrib/blob/master/scala210/main/scala/Try.scala#L25) of `Try`, which is required by the `sequence`'s type signature.
`Try` lives outside of scalaz, since it only appeared in scala 2.10, and scalaz aims to cross-compile to earlier versions).

Answer (score 5):

Starting in `Scala 2.13`, most collections are provided with a [`partitionMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#partitionMap%5BA1,A2%5D(f:A=%3EEither%5BA1,A2%5D):(CC%5BA1%5D,CC%5BA2%5D)) method which partitions elements based on a function returning either `Right` or `Left`.

In our case we can call `partitionMap` with a function that transforms our `Try`s into `Either`s ([`Try::toEither`](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/util/Try.html#toEither:scala.util.Either%5BThrowable,T%5D)) in order to partition `Success`es as `Right`s and `Failure`s as `Left`s.

Then it's just a matter of matching the resulting partitioned tuple of lefts and rights based on whether or not there are lefts:

```
tries.partitionMap(_.toEither) match {
  case (Nil, rights)       => Success(rights)
  case (firstLeft :: _, _) => Failure(firstLeft)
}
// * val tries = List(Success(10), Success(20), Success(30))
//       => Try[List[Int]] = Success(List(10, 20, 30))
// * val tries = List(Success(10), Success(20), Failure(new Exception("error1")))
//       => Try[List[Int]] = Failure(java.lang.Exception: error1)
```

Details of the intermediate `partitionMap` step:

```
List(Success(10), Success(20), Failure(new Exception("error1"))).partitionMap(_.toEither)
// => (List[Throwable], List[Int]) = (List(java.lang.Exception: error1), List(10, 20))
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look on the liftweb Box monad. With the help of the `tryo` constructor function, it gives you exactly the abstraction you are looking for.

With `tryo` you can lift a function into a `Box`. The box then either contains the result from the function or it contains an error. You can then access the box with the usual monadic helper functions (flatMap, filter, etc.), without bothering if the box contains an error or the result form the function.

Example:

```
import net.liftweb.util.Helpers.tryo

List("1", "2", "not_a_number") map (x => tryo(x.toInt)) map (_ map (_ + 1 ))
```

Results to

```
List[net.liftweb.common.Box[Int]] = 
  List(
    Full(2), 
    Full(3), 
    Failure(For input string: "not_a_number",Full(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "not_a_number"),Empty)
  )
```

You can skip the erroneous values with `flatMap`

```
List("1", "2", "not_a_number") map (x => tryo(x.toInt)) flatMap (_ map (_ + 1 ))
```

Results

```
List[Int] = List(2, 3)
```

There are multiple other helper methods, e.g. for combining boxes (while chaining error messages). You can find a good overview here: [Box Cheat Sheet for Lift](http://nerd.kelseyinnis.com/blog/2012/05/16/box-cheat-sheet-for-lift/)

You can use it on its own, no need to use the whole lift framework. For the examples above I used the follwing sbt script:

```
scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-common" % "2.5-RC2"

libraryDependencies += "net.liftweb" %% "lift-util" % "2.5-RC2"
```

Answer (score 0):

These are my 2cents:

```
def sequence[A, M[_] <: TraversableOnce[_]](in: M[Try[A]])
  (implicit cbf:CanBuildFrom[M[Try[A]], A, M[A]]): Try[M[A]] = {
    in.foldLeft(Try(cbf(in))) {
      (txs, tx) =>
        for {
          xs <- txs
          x <- tx.asInstanceOf[Try[A]]
        } yield {
          xs += x
        }
    }.map(_.result())
  }
```