# Using typetags to match for java overloaded vararg method, mapping over Try

Tags: scala

I have an overloaded java method call that can take either String or InetAddress vararg parameters. To reduce complexity I wanted to convert a sequence of strings to a sequence of InetAddresses before calling the java method. In converting a String to an InetAddress I only want to allow valid values

Having see [this on typetags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-2-10-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it) and [this on Try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495678/flatten-scala-try) I came up with:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import java.net.InetAddress
import scala.util.Try

type InetAddr = java.net.InetAddress

def tryMap[A](xs: Seq[Try[A]]) =
  Try(Some(xs.map(_.get))).
     getOrElse(None)

def toInet(address: String): Try[InetAddr] = {
  Try(InetAddress.getByName(address))
}


def stringToInet[A: TypeTag](xs: Seq[A]): Option[Seq[InetAddr]] = typeOf[A] match {
  case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => tryMap(xs.map(toInet)).getOrElse(None)
  case t if t =:= typeOf[InetAddr] => Some(xs)
  case _ => None
}
```

But I get the error

```
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String => scala.util.Try[InetAddr]
 required: A => ?
         case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => tryMap(xs.map(toInet)).getOrElse(None)
```

I am not sure if I am close to getting something workable or wildly off track and would appreciate some guidance in finding a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that even if you know the type tag is equal to the type you want, that doesn't change the type of `xs`, so you would need to do something like this:

```
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
  import java.net.InetAddress
  import scala.util.Try

  def tryMap[A](xs: Seq[Try[A]]) =
    Try(Some(xs.map(_.get))).
      getOrElse(None)

  def toInet(address: String): Try[InetAddress] = {
    Try(InetAddress.getByName(address))
  }

  def stringToInet[A: TypeTag](xs: Seq[A]): Option[Seq[InetAddress]] = typeOf[A] match {
    case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => 
        tryMap(xs.asInstanceOf[Seq[String]].map(toInet)) // don't need the getOrElse, it's already an option
    case t if t =:= typeOf[InetAddress] => 
        Some(xs.asInstanceOf[Seq[InetAddress]])
    case _ => None
  }
```

The `asInstanceOf` is kind of ugly, but necessary to do what you want.