# Pattern matching with OR logic

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

For instance, I have two `Try` objects. I want to get error if one or another fails and process it in the same way:

```
  val t1 = Try(throw new Exception("one"))
  val t2 = Try(throw new Exception("two"))

  (t1, t2) match {
    case (Success(_), Success(_)) => println("It's ok")
    case _ : Failure(e), _) | (_, Failure(e) =>  // Compile error here

      println("Fail", e)                         // Doesn't matter from where e was come 
  }
```

Is it possible to make this code with the same `e` in both failure options compile?

Comment: You can't- you can put  the futures in a list and flatten it as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495678/flatten-scala-try

Comment: Is it so bad if you separate the two failing cases? `case (Failure(e), _) => println(s"Fail $e") 
  case (_, Failure(e)) => println(s"Fail $e")`

Comment: @mfirry Actually, not very bad, but I was wonder if it is possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot combine match patterns this way. You can achieve the desired behaviour this way:

```
t1.flatMap(_ => t2) match {
   case Success(_) => println("It's ok")
   case Failure(e) => prinltn("Fail", e)
}
```

Comment: Interesting technique. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another convinient way, based on the [@Nyavro answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51076204/8398382) is to combine multiple tryes in a single try via for comprhensions:

```
 val tryDoIt = for {
   t1 <- Try(throw new Exception("one"))
   t2 <- Try(throw new Exception("two"))
   t3 <- Try(throw new Exception("three"))
 } yield (t1, t2, t3)

 tryDoIt match {
   case Success((x, y, z)) => println(x,y,z)
   case Failure(e) => println(e.getMessage)
 }
```